# How can I select categories and associate it with a user?

Tags: php, android, wordpress, mobile

I have a question for developing a site in Wordpress.
I need to select from user-area the category and sub-category and associate it with the user but I do not know the best way to do this.

In practice I have to have the ability to enter groups for my user and so I would like to connect to a category so as to have the post relating to that category, being a mobile app must then implement a service to send push notification via a plugin to people associated with that category (group)

How can I do it?

Comment: Are you using woocommerce rest api client ?

Comment: @n9153 no i don't use woocommerce..